# How can you tell the difference between a generated and a selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible, in either the jQuery API or the DOM, to check if an element exists on the page or not?

Consider these two variables:

```
var selected = $('span#mySpan');
var created = $('<span id="mySpan">Testing</span>');
```

Both will return a jQuery object containing a span element. Is there any way to tell that the first exists on the page, and the second one does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(created).parents("html").length
```

Here are some more ways to do the same:

```
$(document).find(created).length
$(created).parents(document).length
```

Or using the [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method that was built for this task. It only accepts DOM nodes, so we need to unwrap it from the jQuery object

```
$.contains(document, created.get(0))
```

A pure DOM way will be to use the [`Node.compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.compareDocumentPosition) method. In the above example,

```
// get the DOM node
var createdNode = created.get(0);
var position = document.compareDocumentPosition(createdNode);
var isNotInDocument = (position & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED) != 0;
```

Comment: Beautiful in its simplicity :)

Comment: It is simple, but not fool-proof :) Consider a node `p` inside `$("<html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>")` will return 1.

Comment: I can live with that; if they're generating a second Html and Body then things are supposed to break ;-)

Comment: `$.contains` looks like the winner. It should be noted that while `compareDocumentPosition` is the 'correct' way, it is not supported cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this, aside from some kind of an extension to the underlying DOM api is to grab a copy of the entire DOM tree and then do a comparison against it.

In your example, won't your second span have no parent?  In valid HTML a span should always have a parent.  Just rules like that, assuming valid HTML/XHTML, might be useful.